# Create numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to create a array of arrays using numpy.full, but i get a error if I set the fill to [1, 1, 1, 1]. Doing the lines below gives this error

```
size = (20, 20)
npArray = np.full(size, [1, 1, 1, 1])    
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (20,20)
```

Should I just use python like so

```
list = [[[1, 1, 1, 1] for y in range(size[1])] for x in range(size[0])]
```

Comment: Did you mean `np.full(size+(4,), [1, 1, 1, 1])`?

Comment: @Divakar Thank you, silly mistake from me :)